# uploadify: no reaction on fileUploadStart()

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I have no reaction or error when i want to upload images with uploadify.
It's possible to select the images, but no upload.
Very strangly i have this only on this hosting !

In the testversion of that website on my hosting, everyting was working.
When i load it onto the hosting of my client; it failed.
You can see it here: http://www.locatevents.com/test.php

Can somebody give me suggestions where to seek about particular hosting settings which can cause this problem ? Maybe path-related ?

Thanks, Dave

Comment: Sorry, i got it i guess. The hosting of my client is php4.4. I know prehistoric ! I asked them to switch it to php5; then i'm convinced it wil work.

Answer (score 1):

Solution, as commented by OP:

Server is using PHP 4.4 and developer is using PHP 5.